# Can I have expandable and non-expandable elements using Accordion?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have spent the last hours trying to find a solution on this, but I cannot find any.
I use [Accordion | jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#sortable) for a list.
In the list there are items that I need to expand to show more content and others that should be just text.

It looks like though that if I break the suggested structure the accordion doesn't work at all.

At this point, I had to add empty divs so that it doesn't break, but I ended up having header that expand with no content to show.

Is there a way to keep the headers that don't need expanding and the ones they do together without everything falling apart?

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="accordion" class="col-xs-12">         
       <h3>Header</h3><div></div>
       <h3>Header</h3><div></div>
       <h3><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Header 3</h3><div><ul id="googlelist">
             <li>Item 1</li>
             <li>Item 2</li>
             <li>Item 3</li>
             <li>Item 4</li>
           </ul>
           </div>             
       <h3>Header</h3><div></div>
       <h3>Header</h3>
         <div>
            <ul id="googlelist">
             <li>Item1</li>
             <li>Item 2</li>
           </ul>
          </div>
       <h3>Header</h3>
          <div><ul id="googlelist">
             <li>Item 1</li>
             <li>Item 2</li>
             <li>Item 3</li>
           </ul></div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you can use a hack using a custom click handler like

```
<div id="accordion" class="col-xs-12">         
    <h3 class="none">Header</h3><div></div>
    <h3 class="none">Header</h3><div></div>
    <h3><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Header 3</h3><div><ul id="googlelist">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>
    </div>             
    <h3>Header</h3><div></div>
    <h3>Header</h3>
    <div>
        <ul id="googlelist">
            <li>Item1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h3>Header</h3>
    <div><ul id="googlelist">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul></div>
</div>
```

then

```
$('#accordion h3.none').click(function (e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
})
$('#accordion').accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sqcbeu7f/)

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for.
One more question: Could I also remove the icon showing at the right in these headers? I can do that using CSS but I was wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: @kat_indo css is the best way to do it... just hide them